Using PostGresSQL Format and Double Quotes
I'm trying to insert some data into postgres function using the 'EXECUTE format' statement.
The string includes double quotes in the style:
"{"id1":'value1',"id2":'value2'}"

When I do:
SELECT test('"{"id1":''value1'',"id2":''value2''}"');

The string is then used in the function
EXECUTE format(' ...%I... ', arg) ...;

The query ends up appending extra double quotes so it becomes:
"""{""id"":'value1',""id2"":'value2'}"""

How can I stop the extra speech marks being added?


From here SQL Syntax: *4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants *, use dollar quoting: SELECT $$"{"id1":''value1'',"id2":''value2''}"$$;  "{"id1":''value1'',"id2":''value2''}" 2) This looks like JSON are you using this in a string field or a JSON field?


May want to look at how JSON is updated... https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html

%I is used for identifiers like table and column names. Not a string like "{"id1":'value1',"id2":'value2'}". You need %s or %L, depending on how you want to treat NULLs.
EXECUTE format(' ...%s... ', arg) ...;

Or
EXECUTE format(' ...%L... ', arg) ...;

See the manual for details
